# ORA-01735 when altering table with inline constraint

Tags: oracle, go

Oracle Version: **Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production**

Query:
   `ALTER TABLE "TAB" ADD "XVAR" CLOB CHECK ("XVAR" IS JSON);`

I can't quite understand what is wrong with this statement. Can someone point out what is wrong with this ?

As far as I understand, the constraint does not need to be named by default. Even naming the constraint has not helped here.

I'm trying to run the query on the DB via the [go-oci8 driver](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8).

The code to do the same is:

```
package main

import (
"database/sql"
"fmt"
_ "github.com/mattn/go-oci8"
)

func main() {
db, err := sql.Open("oci8", "<connectionString>")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer func(db *sql.DB) {
    if err := db.Close(); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}(db)

_sql := `ALTER TABLE "TAB" ADD "XVAR" CLOB CHECK ("XVAR" IS JSON);`

result, err := db.Exec(_sql)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Issue with altering table...")
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected())
```

}

**Output:**

```
Issue with altering table...
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

Is there anything wrong with my query ? Or does it look like an issue with the 3rd party driver I'm using to do the same ?

Comment: As far as Oracle is concerned, nothing wrong with your code. I tested it on 12.2.0.1.0 (which is your database version), works correctly when ran in SQL*Plus. Maybe it has to do something with the 3rd party driver (as you said).

Comment: @Littlefoot ditto for me. Runs for me using sqlplus as well. Just needed some confirmation that this is indeed correct. I'm fairly new to oracle. I've opened an issue regarding the same: https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/issues/346.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the `ALTER` statement:

```
_sql := `ALTER TABLE "TAB" ADD "XVAR" CLOB CHECK ("XVAR" IS JSON)`
```

The semicolon is client statement separator and is not part of the actual statement (for SQL; PL/SQL is a different matter).

Demo of the problem and fix, via dynamic SQL rather than your stack, but same problem and solution:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "TAB" ADD "XVAR" CLOB CHECK ("XVAR" IS JSON);';
END;
/

ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
ORA-06512: at line 2

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "TAB" ADD "XVAR" CLOB CHECK ("XVAR" IS JSON)';
END;
/

Table altered.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fa13def81ce0c2d133023e58d89a776)

Comment: You're right @Alex. This was the same thing suggested by the owner of the repo I was using. I'm marking this as the correct answer. Thank you for your detailed response !